# Putting a Youtube clip in the Google Map infoWindow using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, youtube

For a Udacity project, I'm trying to create a neighborhood map using Google Maps API as well as Knockout and Ajax to use another 3rd party API.  Since nobody else in my class has used Youtube, I decided to focus on bars in my neighborhood and use Ajax to search Youtube for any relevant videos for that bar ( I looked each bar us to ensure that at least one video existed for each ).  I got my map working with just an embedded video, just to ensure that would work, but I'm getting a console error when trying to Ajax call infoWindow specific videos.  Here's the Ajax call.

```
var yt_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search" + markerList[i];
        var ytRequestTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("failed to get Youtube resources");
    }, 8000);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
          //make some room for youtube ajax call and supporting code here.
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: yt_url,
          datatype: "jsonp",
          success: function(response){
            var ytWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: '<object width="425" height="344"><param name="movie" value="am name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src=yt_url type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>'
              })
            ytWindow.open(map, marker);

          }

        })
```

Here's my Codepen if you want to see the related HTML and CSS as well as the entire JS file.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azMGBq

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...src=yt_url type...` is not going to insert the url into the string, you'll have to do some string concatenation `...src='"+yt_url+'" type...`

```
content: '<object width="425" height="344"><param name="movie" value="am name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="'+yt_url+'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>'
```